# React-Native Spotify SDK iOS: Dismiss auth window

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, spotify

I have been developing a react-native application using the following module:

https://github.com/viestat/react-native-spotify

Currently, the application opens the authentication window to login to spotify. I do get a return of success but i'm confused as to how i now get rid of the window that popped up to login with. I understand it should redirect back to my application but it just stays on the same window with logout/ my account buttons.

Any ideas how i would dismiss this window on a returned success message?

```
SpotifyAuth.setClientID('*****','*****', ['streaming', 'playlist-read-private'], (error)=>{
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log('success');
          }
        });
```

[image: Here are my settings in xcode...]

[image: My redirect URI in Spotify app]

Comment: Hi Steve, can you share the project, i need to make sure if you have already added the `callback` in your info.plist(`the call has to be added on web too while creating the application`), did you check this too https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/#setting-up-your-build-environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the code, the login screen (`SpotifyLoginViewController` to be exact), dismisses the screen at [this line of code](https://github.com/viestat/react-native-spotify/blob/91aa5b997b99ed364f88c88673119dfea8d31be1/spotifyModule/ios/SpotifyLoginViewController.m#L65). According to the logic here, if the `redirectURL` that you've passed to the `setClientID` API doesn't match to the redirect URI that you defined in your Spotify developer account (see their [authorization guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)) - the screen will not be dismissed.

I suggest the you put a break-point in this function before it's checking the url scheme and see what's going on there. Either your account is not configured properly, or a wrong URL (or a URL which is not at the expected format by this package) is being sent to this API.

Comment: I have added my URL scheme into my project. I'll grab some screenshots in case it's not as it should be. I did try multiple ways. In some, it said "URI invalid" and in the one that matches my scheme it just doesn't dismiss.

Comment: I still think that the best way would be to debug this code; see what you get for `url.scheme` and what you get in `myScheme`, everything else is just speculating :) I've never worked with the Spotify API or with this package so I'm not sure if I'll be able to help beyond that.. You need to know what is returned from Spotify as the `ur.scheme` to understand what's wrong

Comment: May be a stupid question. How would i do a var_dump/console.log type thing in obj-c?

Comment: you can use `NSLog` which is the equivalent of `console.log`. For example, after assigning the value to `myScheme`, add the following line: `NSLog(@"myScheme: %@, URL scheme: %@", myScheme, url.scheme);`, but you will only see it in iOS logs (not in chrome). using a breakpoint and inspecting the values should be simple too - just click the line number to add a breakpoint and run the project from Xcode

Comment: See added images.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your Redirect URL is configured incorrectly.

1. Make sure your URI is entered in the Spotify My Applications Dashboard.
2. Make sure your URI conforms to the following:

   - All characters in the URI should be **lowercase.**
   - Your URI’s prefix (the part before the first colon) must be unique to your application. It cannot be a general prefix like http.
     Your URI’s prefix must only be used by your application for authenticating Spotify. If you already have a URL scheme handled by your application for other uses, you shouldn’t recycle it.
   - It’s a good convention to have the name of your application in there.
   - You should also have a path component to your URI (the part after the first set of forward slashes, something like `your-app://callback`)